# regex for jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, tankauth

the jmeter still not exclude the .gif OR .png extension from record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) provides "URL Patterns to Exclude" input so you can specify what you want to exclude there.

The tricky part is that the input accepts **patterns** - Perl5-style [regular expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

So if you want to exclude .gif and .png files from being recorded add the following line to aforementioned input:

```
.*\.(gif|png)
```

You might also be interested in [Excluding Certain Domains from the Load Test](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/140841-excluding-certain-domains-from-the-load-test)